# \setmainfont in book document class

Tags: packages, fontspec

Here it is a minimal example of a code which confused me :)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
     \setmainfont{[bpg_ucnobi.ttf]} 


\begin{document}
  \title{სათაური}
  \author{Author}
  \date{2020}
  
  \maketitle\
  \chapter{Ch.}\

\end{document}
```

I run it by means of LuaLaTex
XeLaTex since I am going to use a georgian font as a main font.

It does not work and I do not understand why.

It seems that **\setmainfont** does something bad.

The following is an error message I receive:

```
! No declaration for shape TU/(0)/m/it.
sub@sfcnt ...e forspace shapespace mandatory@arg }
                                              error@fontshape else #1{Fo...

l.16 \chapter
       {Ch.}
?
```

but the code creates title page with **\chapter** commented out.

[image]

The code also work fine with **report** document class.
How to repair the code to use the font which is mentioned in the code with **book** document class correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brackets around the file name are wrong. I don't have your font but try

```
    \setmainfont{bpg_ucnobi.ttf}
```

Comment: :D Thank you a lot. 
Your variant works for me now.
I was using it in that way (with square brackets) in other document classes some time and it worked well but do not with book document class.